# What is the difference between gibbet and gallows?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was just reading this **[communique](https://twitter.com/tonyveitchuk/status/532462529646436352)**:

> We got to the moat - crowds were huge. Went up to the Merchant Marine
>   Memorial on Tower Hill. On the site of the gibbet.

I initially thought of giblet (wrong!) and then gallows. I read this extensive entry **[about gibbeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbeting)** but am no closer to understanding the distinction between gibbet and gallows.

Comment: The gallows is a gibbet used to hang people. Gibbeting is the display afterwards in some kind of cage

Comment: Or were they different in the number of uprights?

Comment: @mplungjan So a gallows is a special case of gibbet?

Comment: General Reference - **gibbet**: [a gallows with a projecting arm at the top, from which the bodies of criminals were formerly hung in chains and left suspended after execution.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gibbet)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The last public execution in England was that of Michael Barrett (aka Fenian), an Irish nationalist who killed 12 people in Clerkenwell. It was in 1868. Someone is bound to be wondering when these grisly things stopped so I offer that by way of useful information.

Comment: @WS2: And ***three days after*** Barret was "publicly hanged", UK law was changed so such barbarity could never be repeated. So I think we can safely say the collective mood of the nation (or at least, TPTB) at the time would not have tolerated the (once "standard") practice of leaving the decaying corpse up there for days or weeks after the execution. In which case it seems unlikely they'd have used a *gibbet* (it was probably a standard "trapdoor platform" gallows, with the body being removed & buried without ceremony shortly after confirmation of death).

Comment: ...anyway, this might all be very interesting (to some people), but it's really all just GR that can easily be established using online resources. ELU isn't an "extended encyclopedia", so I don't understand why the question is still open.

Comment: For a detailed history of the English practice of "hanging in chains" (that is, gibbeting), see [Hanged in Chains](http://thewildpeak.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/hanged-in-chains/), which notes that gibbeting was "regularised" as a punishment by the Murder Act of 1751, where it was one of two approved ways of dealing with the bodies of hanged felons (the other was public dissection). This source also says that "live gibbeting" (amounting to death by caged starvation) might be meted out "until the seventeenth century."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have just realised that this year marked the 50th anniversary of the last execution of any kind in the UK. The last two to go to the gallows were in August 1964, one in Liverpool and the other in Manchester. I am surprised not to have seen any programmes in the media etc. on the subject.

Comment: @WS2: It seems like it was only a year or two ago I watched the 1991 docudrama [*Let Him Have It*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_Him_Have_It) on broadcast TV with my father. He'd always been a lifelong "Flog 'em and hang 'em" supporter until then, but I (greatly helped by that dramatization, admittedly) successfully convinced him revenge has no place in modern justice, and the finality of capital punishment gives a hollow ring to Derek Bentley's eventual full pardon. Whatever - there's certainly nothing there to "celebrate" with "anniversaries".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was an 8 year-old child at the time of the Craig-Bentley case. Around the same time John Chrisie (Rillington Place) was brought to trial for murders which had previously been assumed to have been the work of Timothy Evans, hanged 1949. I was greatly troubled by all this as a child, especially with adults around me clamouring for execution of these various people.

Comment: @WS2: Back when I was a bolshie adolescent, I used to think killing the really bad guys was a reasonable way to go (I kinda swept the possibility of "miscarriages of justice" under the carpet). Even now I sometimes get suckered into thinking the American system could be improved by using some simple painless method (just put them in an airtight chamber filled with nitrogen, and they'll be happy as Larry until they pass out and die). But really, I see it all as barbaric - one step up from mindless suicide bombers.

Comment: @WS2 Thank you for historical context. FF: I have but one `@` summons to give per comment and you already know [how I feel](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/will-there-be-a-2014-community-moderator-election/4785#comment16275_4785) about your commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gallows is a means of execution by hanging.
A gibbet is a similar device used for displaying to corpse after death. 

Usually the corpse would be placed in a cage. Sometimes penalty was carried out using the gibbet, placing a convicted person in the cage alive, either for a limited period or more likely until death (with the corpse probably being left after death as an example "*pour encourager les autres*").

The devices look similar (though there could be significant differences in the construction of either), but had different purposes.

Comment: Please try to support with a definitive source.

Comment: @Kris See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbeting "Gibbeting was a common law punishment, which a judge could impose in addition to execution"; and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallows "A gallows (or scaffold) is a frame, typically wooden, used for execution by hanging, or as a means of torture before execution"

Comment: That information is better incorporated within the answer for everyone's easy visibility.

Answer (score 3):

1828 Websters Dictionary:

Gibbet
GIB'BET, noun A gallows; a post or machine in form of a gallows, on which notorious malefactors are hanged in chains, and on which their bodies are suffered to remain, as spectacles in terrorem.

1. Any traverse beam.

GIB'BET, verb transitive To hang and expose on a gibbet or gallows.

1. To hang or expose on anything going travers, as the beam of a gibbet